# CUDA and STL vector

Tags: stl, cuda

Having just learned that many cpp features (including the stl vector class) do not work in cu files. Even when using them in the host code.

Since I have to use a C++ class which uses STL I cannot compile my CU file which invokes the kernel. (I don't use any STL features in the CU file, but I think the include is the problem.)

I tried to build this by using cmake with

```
cuda_add_executable(
Blah
Blah.cu
BlahKernel.cu
HostCodeWithVector.cpp
)
```

which obviously doesn't work. The question now arises if it's possible to build HostCodeWithVector.cpp with gcc instead of nvcc and the link it somehow..?

Comment: Yes I know about thrust, but I don't want to rewrite the existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since `__host__` is just what runs on your CPU you can compile this part using any compiler (MSVC, gcc) and then link with nvcc result. So you should just leave only GPU interop in CU files, everything else put into CPP.

Comment: Ok.. and how can I tell this cmake..?

Comment: @Nils read documentation of gcc and nvcc. make them produce object files. then take linker from gcc and link them together.

Comment: Thx for ur answer, the problem was trying to build 64bit which (still!) does not work with CUDA on a Mac and not with STL. I did it correct I think. " All of the non CUDA C files are compiled using the standard
     build rules specified by CMAKE and the cuda files are compiled to object
     files using nvcc and the host compiler." Says http://cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html